# Merge and sort an array of numbers in numerical order - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to merge and sort 2 arrays in numerical order.

```
function merge_arrays(a, b) {
    console.log( (a.concat(b)).sort().join(" ") );
}
```

This works fine with single digits in an array, but it doesn't sort numbers with double digits properly.

e.g.:

a: [2, 3, 7, 8, 8,]

b: [7, 8, 13]

will output as: 13 2 3 7 7 8 8 8

Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, I was missing the sort option function inside the .sort()

.sort(function(c,d){return c-d)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The default sort order is lexicographic (not numeric).

Try this instead:

```
function merge_arrays(a, b) {
    console.log( (a.concat(b)).sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }).join(" ") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

See that section
Note: When numbers are sorted alphabetically, "40" comes before "5".

**To perform a numeric sort, you must pass a function as an argument when calling the sort method.**

The function specifies whether the numbers should be sorted ascending or descending.

Meaning This

```
function numOrdA(a, b){ return (a-b); }
```

and your code :

```
a.concat(b)).sort(numOrdA).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c = a.concat(b)
c == [2,3,7,8,8,7,8,13]
c.sort() == [13,2,3,7,7,8,8,8]
```

This is because, when not provided with a comparison function, sort automatically converts the elements of the list it is sorting to strings. In string land "13" < "2".

Check out the [sort documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

So what you probably want is something like this:

```
function compare_number(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

a.concat(b).sort(compare_number);
```

And to fully answer your question:

```
a.concat(b).sort(compare_int).join(" ");
```